# Automating eggifying of old Plone products

Tags: python, plone, zope, egg

Does anyone know a script which would wrap old Products namespace style Plone add-on to an egg?

- Generate setup.py
- Create directory structure

Other actions needed?

Any pitfalls in the eggifying process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script taking care of pesky details:

https://github.com/miohtama/eggify

Answer (score 3):

With paster.

```
paster -t basic_namespace Products.myOldProducts
```

Then, you have the structure, you will have to remove the "myOldProducts" directory and replace it with your actual oldProducts.